# How can i wait for chrome.tabs.executeScript?

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome-extension, browser, firefox-addon

At the moment i'm using a timeout like this:

```
function injectScript() {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript({
    file: "inject.js"
  });
}

chrome.pageAction.onClicked.addListener((tab) => {
  injectScript();
  setTimeout(() => {
    doSomething(tab)
  }, 1000);
});
```

I want to replace the `setTimeout` to a better alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function injectScript() {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript({
    file: "inject.js"
  },
  ()=>{
   doSomething(tab)
  });
}
```